# Azure: Is it possible to delete a restore point in azure backup?

Tags: azure

I have a test restore point (it's older than 30 days) I wanted to delete to save on the cost. I tried via azure portal the only option I found is to delete the backup data, not the restore point of a particular vm.

I'm currently using classic deployment and the VMs are deployed using classic deployment.

Comment: Why do you want to delete the restore point? If you have configured the `Retention range` in the backup policy, it is unnecessary to delete it manually.

Comment: I mistakenly inputted extremely long duration on my test run and now it's causing trouble on the storage space for preceeding backup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for as I know, It's impossible to delete a restore point in Azure backup. According to [delete backup date](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-azure-manage-vms#delete-backup-data) in the official doc.

> Unlike the process for restoring recovery points, when you delete
>   backup data, you **can't choose specific recovery points to delete**. If
>   you delete your backup data, you **delete all associated recovery
>   points.**

Moreover, It's not necessary to select specific recovery points to delete as you could [customize retention range](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-azure-backup-faq#can-i-customize-retention-policies) in backup policy. The Retention means how long data needs to be stored. Refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-introduction-to-azure-backup#how-does-azure-backup-differ-from-azure-site-recovery).

Answer (score 2):

Now it is possible thought portal, powershell and CLI.

First of all you need to stop backup (retain backup).
Disable soft delete in RSV properties. 
After that find appropriate RG - AzureBackupRG-location_of_vm, example: `AzureBackupRG_westus2_1` Remember to check "Show hidden types" in RG. 
Last step is to delete restore points in this RG. `You only delete restore point, not backup from vault`

*

```
*PORTAL**:
Temporarily stop the backup and retain backup data.

To move virtual machines configured with Azure Backup, do the following steps:

Find the location of your virtual machine.
Find a resource group with the following naming pattern: AzureBackupRG_<location of your VM>_1. For example, AzureBackupRG_westus2_1
In the Azure portal, check Show hidden types.
Find the resource with type Microsoft.Compute/restorePointCollections that has the naming pattern AzureBackup_<name of your VM that you're trying to move>_###########.
Delete this resource. This operation deletes only the instant recovery points, not the backed-up data in the vault.
After the delete operation is complete, you can move your virtual machine.
Move the VM to the target resource group.

Resume the backup.
```

[Link to MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/move-limitations/virtual-machines-move-limitations#virtual-machines-with-azure-backup)

Answer (score 0):

I got an 'internal system error' while trying to delete the restore point. This was because the VM had already been deallocated. I turned it back on, then was able the delete the restore point successfully, then shut the VM down again.